# Why i can not connect to mysql db using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have used jdbc driver before.But for this piece of program i can't connect to the db.This doesn't throw any exception or anything. Just won't connect. I couldn't find a solution online either.Below is the code i tried to run :( Please help in solving this. Thank you in advance :)

```
public class HeapMySql<T extends Comparable<T>> implements HeapInterface {

static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Heap"; 

static final String USERNAME = "root";
static final String PASSWORD = "";

private int size = 0 ;
String sql;
static Statement stmt = null;
static Connection conn = null;
static ResultSet rs = null;

public void HeapMySql(){

    try
    {       
        sql = "CREATE TABLE testHeap (index integer, value integer);";  
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }catch(Exception e){

    }        

}

public static void main(String [] arg){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

        System.out.println("Creating table in given database..."); //lets create a table in our database
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        HeapMySql test1 = new HeapMySql<>();

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){

    }finally{

    }
```

Comment: if no exception is found this means its connected

Comment: how can you say that it does not throw any error?you havent written ex.printstachtrace

Comment: In `catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)` block put `ex.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: Which statements are getting printed on the console?

Comment: i don't get inside of the try block of the constructor

Comment: where is the constructor here?Did you read what me and @Oli told you to do?

Comment: And put `e.printStackTrace()` on the inside of `catch (Exception e)`.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry.i editted the code before putting here.Anyway those things don't matter.Right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A constructor does not have a return type*: [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Remove `void` from `public void HeapMySql()` and it will do the work.
Also as said in comments, you should print the `stacktrace` in your `catch` blocks. This makes it easy to understand the exception and resolve the problem.